# where can i find g+ api php docs like that of facebook?

Tags: php, api, google-plus, google-api-php-client

I am developing web app using g+ login and i need many information of the user from his g+ account. I'm currently using google-api-php-client API. Is there a well documentation for it like that of facebook? I have searched many sites but couldnt find any. Plz suggest some links..

Answer (score 0):

Try here: [Google+ API - Google+ Platform](https://developers.google.com/+/api/)